# Image of norm map for local field 

Tags: galois-theory, nt.number-theory, local-rings, local-fields, class-field-theory

Let  $F$ be a finite extension of $Q_2$ (2-adic field) or $F_2((x))$ (function field). Let $E/F$ be a separable extension of degree $2$.

1. What is the image of the norm map $N_{E/F}$?
2. In particular - is it true that the index $[F^{\star} : N_{E/F}(E^{\star})]$   depends only on the ramification $e(E|F)$?

Comment: What does "some extension" mean? If you meant it to be a finite extension or an algebraic extension, please say so. Also, is the quadratic extension in the function field case supposed to be Galois or not? 

Comment: Thanks for you comment KConard. I have edited the question. 

Comment: Just a remark: while (as the answers below show) it is not true that $[F^\times : N_{E/F} E^\times]$ has anything to do with ramification, it is true for any finite abelian extension of local fields that $[\mathcal{O}_F^\times : N_{E/F} \mathcal{O}_E^\times] = e_{E/F}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment David. It is very useful for me. Would you suggest a reference for this result? I am also trying to understand the image of groups $1 + \pi^t \mathcal{O}_E$, $t \in \mathbb{Z}$ under the norm map in above situation. Do you have any comments for these groups?  

Comment: Serre's "Local Fields" is the bible here. Milne's notes on local class field theory (from his website) are also very good. 

As for the subgroups you mention: if t is positive and reasonably large, the p-adic logarithm map will give an isomorphism between $(1 + \pi^t \mathcal{O}_E, \times)$ and $(\pi^t \mathcal{O}_E, +)$, and the norm on the left-hand side corresponds to the trace on the right, which reduces it to a much easier question. For t positive but small there might be some messier behaviour. I don't know what the question means for $t < 0$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As KConrad points out, you perhaps mean to say that $F$ is a *finite* extension of $\mathbf{Q}_2$ or of $\mathbf{F}_2((x))$, and that the quadratic extesnions $E|F$ is *separable* (and hence galoisian) in the second case.

With this interpretation of the question, $N_{E|F}(E^\times)$ is a closed subgroup of index $2$ in $F^\times$, and every closed subgroup of index $2$ in $F^\times$ is of this form.  In particular, the ramification index $e_{E|F}$ does *not* determine the subgroup in question.

For more on this, see the relevant chapter in Serre's *Corps locaux* (=Local fields) or the book by Fesenko and Vostokov, among many other places.

**Addendum**.  In the same vein as David Speyer's example, it might also be instructive to work out the case $F=\mathbf{F}_2((x))$,by using "Artin-Schreier   theory" instead of "Kummer theory".  Cyclic quadratic extensions of $F$ correspond to $\mathbf{F}_2$-lines $D\subset F/\wp(F)$, where $\wp$ is the endomorhphism $t\mapsto t^2-t$ of the additive group of $F$.  The quotient $F/\wp(F)$ carries a natural filtration, coming from the filtration on the additive group $F$, so every line $D$ has a *level* in this filtration.  The ramification index of the cyclic quadratic extension $E_D=F(\wp^{-1}(D))$ of $F$ corresponding to $D$ depends only on this level.

It would be interesting to work out the norm subgroup $N_{E_D|F}(E_D^\times)\subset F^\times$ for each line $D$.

By the way, the [Second Extended Edition](http://www.maths.nott.ac.uk/personal/ibf/book/book.html) of Fesenko-Vostokov is available online.

**Addendum 2**.  See [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/84274/totally-ramified-p-extension-over-f-qx/84298#84298) for a generalisation from $p=2$ to arbitrary primes $p$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I can not read the fourth line of your reply, would you please edit it a little bit? Thanks. 

Comment: Is it better now ?

Comment: Yes, surely it is. Thank you very much for your reply.   

Answer (score 12):

It might be worth working the example of $\mathbb{Q}_2$. Recall that $u \in \mathbb{Q}_2$ is a square if and only if $u$ is of the form $4^k (1+8 \ell)$ for $\ell \in \mathbb{Z}_2$. So $\mathbb{Q}_2^{\times} / (\mathbb{Q}_2^{\times})^2$ has order $8$, with representative elements being $1$, $3$, $5$, $7$, $2$, $6$, $10$ and $14$. This is an important computation for two reasons:

(1) Quadratic extensions of a characteristic zero field are of the form $K(\sqrt{a})$ for some nonsquare $a$, and two different $a$'s give the same extension if there ratio is a square. So there are $7$ quadratic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_2$. The unramified one is $\mathbb{Q}_2(\sqrt{5})$.

(2) If $L$ is any quadratic extension, then $(\mathbb{Q}_2^\times)^2 \subset N_{L/\mathbb{Q}_2} (L^\times)$ as, for $a \in \mathbb{Q}_2$, we have $N(a)=a^2$. So we can describe the norm group by giving its image in the $8$ element group $\mathbb{Q}^{\times}_2/(\mathbb{Q}_2^{\times})^2$.

So, for example, in $\mathbb{Q}_2(\sqrt{3})$, the norms are elements of the form $a^2 - 3 b^2$. A little checking shows that the image in $\mathbb{Q}^{\times}_2/(\mathbb{Q}_2^{\times})^2$ is represented by $\{ 1, 1-3 \cdot 2^2,  3^2 -3,  1 - 3 \} \equiv \{ 1, 5, 6, 10 \}$. You can enjoy writing down the $4$ element subgroup of $\{ 1,3,5,7,2,6,10,14 \}$ corresponding to each of the $7$ quadratic extensions.