# Totally ramified p-extension over $F_q((X))$

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $K=F_q((X))$, from Artin-Schreier theory, for a cyclic extension $L/K$ of degree p, we have $L=K(x)$, $x^p-x=\alpha$. So when $L/K$ is totally ramified, could we find some $x$ s.t the corresponding $\alpha$ has valuation -1? or $\alpha$ has some bounded valuation independent of $L$? Thanks!

Comment: No. Take $\alpha = X^{-n}, (p,n)=1$. 

Comment: You need to use the quotient field $K[x^{-1}]$ of the ring $K$. Try for example $\alpha=1/x$.

Comment: @Jyrki: Huh? $K$ is a field. Maybe you are confused by the notation.

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't have written so many $X$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Artin-Schreier theory gives a bijection between the set of all degree-$p$ cyclic extension of a field $K$ of prime characteristic $p$ and the set of all $\mathbf{F}_p$-lines in the $\mathbf{F}_p$-space $K^+/\wp(K^+)$, where $\wp$ is the endomorphism $x\mapsto x^p-x$ of the additive group $K^+$ (thought of as an $\mathbf{F}_p$-space).

When $K=k((T))$ for some finite extension $k|\mathbf{F}_p$ of degree $f=[k:\mathbf{F}_p]$, the space $K^+/\wp(K^+)$ can be explicitly computed, along with its filtration.  This is done for example in [arXiv:0909.2541](http://arxiv.org/abs/0909.2541), from which the following is extracted.

Denote by $\frak{o}$ the ring of integers of $K$, and by $\frak{p}\subset\frak{o}$
the unique maximal ideal of $\frak{o}$.  Concretely, we have ${\frak{o}}=k[[T]]$ and
${\frak{p}}=T{\frak{o}}$.

The filtration on the additive group $K^+$ is given by the powers $({\frak{p}}^n)$ of
$\frak{p}$, indexed by $n\in\mathbf{Z}$. It induces a filtration on the $\mathbf{F}_p$-space $\overline{K^+}=K^+/\wp(K^+)$.  We denote the
induced filtration by $\overline{{\frak{p}}^n}$; we have
$\overline{\frak{p}}=\{0\}$, and the codimension at each step is
given by 
$$
\{0\}
\subset_1\overline{\frak{o}}
\subset_f\overline{\frak{p}^{-1}}
\cdots
\subset_f\overline{{\frak{p}}^{-pi+1}}
=\overline{{\frak{p}}^{-pi}}
\subset_f\cdots
\quad\subset\overline{K^+}
$$
Here, $i$ is any integer $>0$, and an
inclusion of $\mathbf{F}_p$-spaces $E\subset_rE'$ means that $E$ is a codimension-$r$
subspace of $E'$.

The unramified degree-$p$ extension of $K$ corresponds to the $\mathbf{F}_p$-line $\overline{\frak{o}}$ (which can be canonically identified with $\mathbf{F}_p$ using the trace map $k\to\mathbf{F}_p$).

So every other line $D$ in this infinite-dimensional $\mathbf{F}_p$-space $K^+/\wp(K^+)$ corresponds to a ramified cyclic degree-$p$ extension $L=K(\wp^{-1}(D))$ of $K$.  If the **level** of $D$ in the displayed filtration is $m$ (say), in the sense that $m>0$ is the smallest integer such that $D\subset\overline{{\frak{p}}^{-m}}$, then the unique ramification break of $\mathrm{Gal}(L|K)$ occurs at $m$.

**Addendum**. On my screen, the \overline does't seem to have any effect, which is very confusing.  It is best to read p.17 of the arXiv version referred to above, or 409 of the [published version](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8EHtI8F9qdIYWI5YTdmNzUtNmRkMC00NmRiLTliZjAtMTdkNmM0ZjBhMDEy) (*Journal of the Ramanujan Mathematical Society* **25** (2010) 4, 393--417).

Comment: Dear Dalawat, thanks for your answer. So in this case, the different of a totally ramified p-extension can be arbitarily small, (I guess it doesn't happen in the mixed character case, say, $\mathbf{Z}_p$ ), and the smaller it becomes, (or the corresponding \textbf{level} grows?), this extension is more close to an inseparable extension?

Comment: On the contrary, as the level $m$ of $D$ grows, so does the valuation $v_L({\frak{D}}_{L|K})$ of the different ${\frak{D}}_{L|K}$ of $L=K(\wp^{-1}(D))$   over $K$; by Hilbert's formula
$$v_L({\frak{D}}_{L|K})=(1+m)(p-1).$$